# Trace and Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

**Give an example of a real vector space $V$ and $T \in L (V)$ such that $T$ has no zero eigenvalues and trace $(T^2)=0$**.

Let $V\in \mathbb R^3$ and $T$ be an operator corresponding to the matrix. Then we have $$ M(T) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 &  0  \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$ Then $M (T^2)  = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} -1 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 &  1  \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]$

Then trace $(T^2) = 0 $.

Does my example work?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example work, and I can give you an example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ If you take :
$$
M(T)=\left(\begin{matrix}
a & \frac{-a}{2}\\
a & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
So we have the eigenvalues of $M(T)=\{\frac{a}{2}(1+i) \; ; \; \frac{a}{2}(1-i)\}$
and
$$
M(T^2)=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{a^2}{2} & \frac{-a^2}{2}\\
a^2 & \frac{-a^2}{2}
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Comment: Your example looks perfect! But I am curious that your eigenvalues are complex values, so are they still valid on real vector space? Please enlighten me!

Comment: @needhelp the requirement was that the eigenvalues couldn't be zero, not that they couldn't be complex.

Comment: @0mnomonomnom got it, thanks!

Comment: @needhelp Some of the eigenvalues in your example are complex too. In fact if $T$ has all real eigenvalues none of which is zero, then $\text{Tr}(T^2)$ is strictly positive because the eigenvalues of $T^2$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $T$. In other words, any example that meets your requirement has to entail complex eigenvalues.

Comment: @KimJongUn Thanks for your explanation!